# Pseudoinverse of rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

> Prove that $$(xy^T)^{+} = (x^Tx)^{+}(y^Ty)^{+}yx^T$$
>   where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A^{+}$ is defined to be such that $AA^{+}A = A$.

Comment: $AA^+A = A$ does not describe $A$ uniquely, so I doubt that the formula can hold in this generality... Do you mean a specific type of pseudoinverses?

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$, then $xy^\top$ is the zero matrix, so anything can be the pseudoinverse.

So now assume $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero. Then $(x^\top x)^+ = (x^\top x)^{-1}$ and $(y^\top y)^+ = (y^\top y)^{-1}$ are just scalars.
\begin{align}
(xy^\top) (xy^\top)^+ (xy^\top)
&= (xy^\top) (x^\top x)^+ (y^\top y)^+ y x^\top (xy^\top)
\\
&= (x^\top x)^{-1} (y^\top y)^{-1} \; xy^\top y x^\top x y^\top
\\
&= xy^\top.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

There is a formula for the pseudoinverse of the product of two matrices.
$$(AB)^+ = (A^+AB)^+(ABB^+)^+$$
The pseudoinverse of a vector has a simple formula.
$$v^+ = \frac{v^T}{v^Tv} \;=\; (v^Tv)^+v^T$$
Although it looks strange, the expression on the far RHS has the advantage that it remains valid when $v=0$.

We also have the Penrose conditions:
$\quad A^+AA^+\!= A^+,\quad AA^+A = A$

Apply the product formula and the Penrose conditions to evaluate
$$\eqalign{
(v^+v)^+ &= ((v^+)^+v^+v)^+\;(v^+vv^+)^+ = (v)^+(v^+)^+ = v^+v \\
}$$
Now apply the above formulas to the outer product of two vectors.
$$\eqalign{
(xy^T)^+
 &= \Big(x^+xy^T\Big)^+\;\Big(xy^Ty^{T+}\Big)^+ \\
 &= \Big((x^Tx)^+x^Txy^T\Big)^+\;\Big(xy^Ty(y^Ty)^+\Big)^+ \\
 &= \Big(y^{T+}(x^Tx)^+(x^Tx)\Big)\;\Big((y^Ty)(y^Ty)^+x^+\Big) \\
 &= y(y^Ty)^+(y^Ty)(y^Ty)^+\;\,(x^Tx)^+(x^Tx)(x^Tx)^+x^T \\
 &= y\,(y^Ty)^+\;\,(x^Tx)^+x^T \\
 &= (x^Tx)^+(y^Ty)^+\;yx^T \\
}$$

Comment: What kind of pseudoinverse is the first formula for? Is it for the strongest notion, or for the general (non-unique) one? Hermitian or not?

Comment: It's valid for the Moore-Penrose inverse. It's probably not applicable to other generalized inverses.

Comment: Do you have a reference or a proof?